# MS Access: show only the max and min row using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, max, min

I have a little Problem with sql again :)
In this example I have to show the max ekpreis in one row and the min ekpreis in a second row. But with all the other data aswell. I tried select max(ekpreis) but that didnt worked.

[image]

I tried this:

SELECT ARTBEZ, max(ekpreis)
FROM artst
Group by artbez;

But this just returns all the rows and not just the max row.

Comment: What query are you using now? What didn't work? What do you expect the query results to look like? Wasn't quite clear from initial post.

Comment: You say that `SELECT ARTBEZ, max(ekpreis) FROM artst Group by artbez` just returns all the rows, but that is because each row has a different value in `artbez`, as far as I can tell. In addition, you cannot just say "the max price", you must say the max price *for* something, for example, "the max price for all rows", "the max price for each paper type".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to try with the following  query

SELECT * FROM  artst Where EKPREIS = (SELECT MAX(EKPREIS)  FROM  artst) Or EKPREIS = (SELECT MIN(EKPREIS)  FROM  artst)

It is retrieve only two row with Maximum of EKPREIS And Minimum of EKPREIS

Comment: this answer was just perfect. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, are you using a GROUP BY?

If so then you just do something like this

```
SELECT MAX(EKPREIS) as MaxVal, MIN(EKPREIS) as MinVal
```

Comment: I tried something like this:

SELECT ARTBEZ, max(ekpreis)
FROM artst
Group by artbez;

But this just shows me every row. Not just the max row.

Comment: You were on the right track. However, you should group first by ARTNR. You want to group them by their unique id.

Comment: hmm if I group by ARTNR I get the same results. Every row is shown and not only the max row.

Comment: SELECT artst.ARTNR, Max(artst.EKPREIS) AS MaxvonEKPREIS
FROM artst
GROUP BY artst.ARTNR;

Comment: I think I was misunderstanding your question, I posted a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

To select record with highest EKPREIS

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM artst ORDER BY EKPREIS DESC
```

To select record with lowest EK

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM artst ORDER BY EKPREIS ASC
```

To get them together use UNION select

Comment: You too NoPyGod. Thank you for your efforts! :)